# Indexing a combination of records, where the key of one is a subset of the other with different values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum of keys for a configuration object, that renders a [Material-UI Drawer Component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/), where the component in the drawer either matches one single component or a group of components in **sections** per sub-topic:

```js
export enum InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys {
  POLICY_HOLDERS = "policyHolders",
  INSURANCE_PROVIDERS = "providers",
  INSURANCE_TYPE = "type",
  CLAIMS = "claims",
}

export enum InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys {
  POLICY_MEMBERS = "policyMembers",
}

export type InsuranceTopicKeys =
  | InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys
  | InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys;

export enum SectionKeys {
  CLAIMANTS = "claimants",
  FULFILLED_CLAIMS = "fullfilledClaims",
  UNFULFILLED_CLAIMS = "unfullfilledClaims",
}
```

and the configuration object looks like this:

```js
export const TOPICS: Record<
  InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys,
  TopicConfiguration | TopicConfigurationGrouped
> = {
  [InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.POLICY_HOLDERS]: {
    key: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.POLICY_HOLDERS,
    secondaryKey: InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys.POLICY_MEMBERS,
    title: "Policy Holders",
    component: (props: TopicDrawerProps) => (
      <TopicDrawer hasSecondary={true} {...props} />
    ),
    topicSelector: keyedTopicSelector.showAll,
    secondaryTopic: {
      key: InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys.POLICY_MEMBERS,
      primaryKey: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.POLICY_HOLDERS,
      title: "Policy Members",
      component: (props: TopicDrawerProps) => (
        <TopicDrawer isSecondary={true} {...props} />
      ),
      topicSelector: keyedTopicSelector.showRelated,
    },
  },
  [InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.INSURANCE_PROVIDERS]: {
    key: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.INSURANCE_PROVIDERS,
    title: "Policy Holders",
    component: TopicDrawerSimple,
    topicSelector: keyedTopicSelector.showAll,
  },
  [InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.INSURANCE_TYPE]: {
    key: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.INSURANCE_PROVIDERS,
    title: "Policy Holders",
    component: TopicDrawerSimple,
    topicSelector: keyedTopicSelector.showAll,
  },
  [InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS]: {
    key: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS,
    title: "Claims",
    component: TopicDrawerGroup,
    topicSelectorCreator: createMultiKeyedTopicSelector,
    sections: [
      SectionKeys.CLAIMANTS,
      SectionKeys.FULFILLED_CLAIMS,
      SectionKeys.UNFULFILLED_CLAIMS,
    ],
  },
};

export type SectionConfig = {
  key: SectionKeys;
  title: string;
};

export const SECTIONS: Record<SectionKeys, SectionConfig> = {
  [SectionKeys.CLAIMANTS]: {
    key: SectionKeys.CLAIMANTS,
    title: "Claimants",
  },
  [SectionKeys.FULFILLED_CLAIMS]: {
    key: SectionKeys.FULFILLED_CLAIMS,
    title: "Fulfilled Claims",
  },
  [SectionKeys.UNFULFILLED_CLAIMS]: {
    key: SectionKeys.UNFULFILLED_CLAIMS,
    title: "Unfulfilled Claims",
  },
};
```

The configurations (`TopicConfiguration`, `SecondaryTopicConfiguration` and `TopicConfigurationGrouped`) share a base type, that they extend:

```js
export interface BaseTopicConfig {
  key: InsuranceTopicKeys;
  title: string;
  secondaryKey?: InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys;
  secondaryTopic?: SecondaryTopicConfiguration;
}

export interface TopicConfiguration extends BaseTopicConfig {
  topicSelector: TopicSelector;
  component: TopicComponent;
}
export interface SecondaryTopicConfiguration extends TopicConfiguration {
  primaryKey: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys;
}
export interface TopicConfigurationGrouped extends BaseTopicConfig {
  topicSelectorCreator: TopicSelectorCreator;
  component: TopicComponentGroup;
  sections: SectionKeys[];
}
```

However there're times when I'd like to look up the config of `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS`, and shortcut having to 'prove' to TS that it's config is only ever going to be of the type `TopicConfigurationGrouped`. For legacy reasons I can't split the config up, as well are situations where I want to access the shared keys.

So I was hoping I could create a subset of 'keys', and have the union of two records (see below), not a record with it's values being a union of types (`Record<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys, TopicConfiguration | TopicConfigurationGrouped>`.

```js
// subset that match config of type TopicConfigurationGrouped 
export type TopicGroups = InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS
```

And then make the type of `TOPICS`:

```js
const TOPICS: Record<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys, TopicConfiguration> | Record<TopicGroups, TopicConfigurationGrouped>
```

But now when I go to get my config with this helper function:

```js
const isPrimaryTopic = (
  topicType: string
): topicType is InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys =>
  Object.values(InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys).includes(
    topicType as InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys
  );

const getConfig = (
  configKey: string
):
  | SecondaryTopicConfiguration
  | TopicConfiguration
  | TopicConfigurationGrouped
  | undefined =>
  isPrimaryTopic(configKey)
    ? TOPICS[configKey as InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys]
    : Object.values(TOPICS).find(
        (topicConfig) => topicConfig?.secondaryKey === configKey
      )?.secondaryTopic;
```

I get this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys' can't be used to index type 'Record<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys, TopicConfiguration> | Record<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS, TopicConfigurationGrouped>'.
> Property '[InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.POLICY_HOLDERS]' does not exist on type 'Record<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys, TopicConfiguration> | Record<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS, TopicConfigurationGrouped>'.(7053)

How can I configure the type in my configuration mapping object (TOPICS, and/or in the linked playground TOPICS_TWO) so that this helper function (and others) can infer that the `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys` type can index the union of the different Records?

---

Additional type to make this a working example are in this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljiQDsBXPASUYGdmoVG0kAFQhhgaAApRQKKAE8A0klmc4Ab3Jw44gPIAZNgGEAmgH0AEnoAiAUQQBlOAF4CkADZjZZiK4AmSKJz4ADQacGwAcnYAqggAguEG1ibiCNoAamw29k4uOABuwH4BwaER0XEJSYJG4tY5+DCyYEglmga6sWwAsg7O+GiuKKCBIQC+lDR08EysYVw8fALComh2SGgQjD4yCkoq6po6+sYmXdZdAEK2vS7eHl1IIABG-iPk41S00PCNzXPcvH4QhEYkUyicoQAPv8FkDlmJJNI5GDOFCYYCliDVutNttkXsKJ8pgwWHg1hhgJsUWpQu1Ol14oIbv1BtJGDA3poAGJRXRcti6XTWSwmOndZmYZiuVyYYDSpA+AyskCcuBRcI8vkCoUisU9erMRiS6Wy+WK5VvD6-JBweHY1zrGDQHIACidKwAXOjFsCViiAJROAB8cDyEEKhI2XHgAGslAq7WsHRhnc4DnBOAALCAAd1i0q9bqxXo4AJ9doDwbgUc43iQADpXBAAOYugAGWdzcBQ0rgEEwcAAJKp3WJRm3-SFNJ2c8hBjAFYXR2gS-MMb7QXtA44g6FNDW642W+2Z3AiPOFXAnUOR1jx5P3oTrbasUnHdADEQUE6oK7QpxHUpRgvXJGAgJRKcr2Lb04SxFFyG3ENVAzbM8wLF8VjfFMoFIFDcznb9FwwsQsJ-OBRkjTZOHgNAvwXLopTAsEE1fJBkzI5wXX-QDNhAnjGAg0Jl1XMtYL9PYEKrF10xnfNXELRDqyow8m1bDtUO7Xt+xvZdRjgTBnWHACKU2e9IJnAiFx8BSqwPB0jzU09z0InwoJ0u99MM1RjLA0yJzGf1CUmb4ryaG07UsXgc38SQRBUNNQijWVmy9O0DE2ZKFl8xg4GhNKMuAZssqAgBxHBmGaHwKE0TMUE4clcR2AB+L0nggOs+GquBgHqnEtma1r2odTrHwmL56GffLwE2Jh4E4sAcDAThUqxSKUGiqBYqWxSACk7AADXrawHRAWaKGCiawuItB0umxhZrKiAKtdBa4pWlY1o2rbOF2g6jpOs7KBreAIqi-xXXTJLCsg2reqjPFZByTAewAyCeoa-q5CRlGkDGd6xE+mLFp+qTQgAHh8YA8l3TRNDJzgwD4INVCh5t6zAmAHVGMmAHoGaZ8mecp6mEMo6NrsJqA7FAMAHQhpSjUK8j8bQSXvsUri6eFmnafpxnGGZ1n2eATmkG5vn9Z13ntdFoGqJB1awagR7ns45DWeViWnfV0mtapnW-eplmCrZjmuet-29zgMmA9p1R8B8oDAm6nKPYAMjTqPaYV5L60Tqj6xAFAwBdF188YRSKf91Q7GsAxBDYbRIgAbXLgBdY3TfN7X-XGbPeatoXI8CsbiWB21tHEQw7C9ZANigHwydKNdyyxREi-xZRIPyxWit4bLcuu9Ld+KzYXcq8gQwSzRm9LWFMRWdedhResjkMUwLF0LI7Dbr1000OMsgRL3w3BIKQG9djKFfnod+5grDXEgtOPqCMwTAPXImZBz89jQOOKYM4lwEFRzDkgL0+BxB3DQIjLwvhXitFphsO6s1CyvSWirNWxMNZZ2jqDda4NYYYwRo4EcUBmBmzUPWCRLDOB6R5rHB82dlykWgF6QBLFMJsXfFAPOqE5KIIzJguQdo-5cMAWg1e6j4ZYKgW-E4+Crj2D0ZoBaSJIFmLEgicBVjOA4NgZ-b+jirwmwdKQ8h7hKFwAeM8WhASGGQHuuyZhxM2Hew4b7bOuseEbW6nDRqcghEwBEWI1QEj6xSJkbHTQ8j0mKI0dhFR8YfAYPYtAbR+E2IuT0aMSCXTQi3xXu4sBLiX5lBiPERIyRUgZG-r-Gk2dTEwQfh4oZ2CRkVHGSkdImRCEKKCSQggoSPBwGoUUVU+5cBxKYV7XhUsZYOj0TU5pUB6myDUSRWpP5WloVcN0yCfTRKLMGRA4ZkRRmVBMNUWoMz-5wHmXfdBa9PGb28assZSQNlTO2bTYhISKFUO8CcuhZzGEJKuRtaW4A7lENYo855rz7SaM+bo0IPSb5wvMUsoF2C9Q-2MXMpQbiAVPyRfWbl9zdmkKVEMFUhKlLEpgMk65597nUs0Z+VAP4vS0XVUgBirgmINKaZovR5dlpwGblw0C4EuUdG6IyOwATLVUmwZqfkgphSihtT0B1-EX7qhddqd1oqo5tx+aNIkIVnyOsYMfZKOR0zzKjSiLq2KMwFOAIwZsFAKKjxCuPWu9dG6RFnjiBeZNE17CCHAKNMbCpX1mWa8tUC9R2qhVHBNPrrX0jtWK02ErlR8A5HQllDaO1QP9W63UnqeX1oAfyqto7vHjp1B6+k9qiHioIFyKUpoHSuUlcMIdvzG3eL9byV1y7uWtr5UA+dJkBLYNPVqCdK7xQ9uCQQKIRpt1yl3XAfd0rQ3ZvDfQdNC4oDIwEHAC4dVQE1ubPW2F-SAVJqEhu6iUgM1dWMrkyBLUFmgIEV4rDBjZB2jw4RwxWI4On0YFmnNIH2T+Ag+FKjIcaMMGoAuLYKhoMAR3rG9MDzNEqyUThRK5yZokqmhc9kdGLrwFA0x9ANoKOkdYyffeQEONcZ8CofjhV2PpmcZym9bKBlCsgZwOT40FOMfA8po+bHNNn3KpVbTTBdNQZg-p+DgmVXYTVd+ZR11ROBZ-F1WJkn5WOblefYjd7TXHubm3Oj5AeY827JgMD1ZaoZvTfBwQk9p6hVEBm8gk0sTn3ivhu0FmX7cqCjZhW1EJ5TwMHYcFAB1bQHo0Rz2gIvMzgrEWWcrT5mjOtoT9dLXaKrY31OZWc4wc+Co63pj+SA2rI2X42I-vA+wV7aaIf+aAur2DdtwK-pipBljN4CoIyRnbMDbHnHsWunZvb9m4qOfi6JUdIvxOiy6KRCqvqpJ3HATW6SyaZL4XVVT+TCl6WKZI4m5So5VM0EJupMKDX+Y+bJaUxqSNGJnUdudQ2Hu3csz4l7BCHFcOM1Y+7W3lnWOe3tq7DP0mBM+2Q77kSXjFBiRJwHiS3qkqJnFThPO6aw9-OjEjiPRHI5KWUuAsiuGY6xfj4LqjGm660RZdpVlOmhtZUh0722VkgrWWiyZWyDu8vJ6Zy3rOTPItt6iiZmz-Hrr5wc8Jxy-vZwB5c+X5LZa4ypeomluOXkG9jwywn3zmW-Mp+7rx9YUVgohdYQ7s7Xcncz8KnP6yHd+4+++-nYS8U0OF-90X4fHbXMj5ShRhvaWJ7eY8xlRO0+9Izwitn3jL3O8Lyz4fHuRVTrfXs-A-7Tmypk9F+XSqY899VXRYLWrCK6v1Qnw12FicJa9Oannx6Z9dvCEyb1d6X5LsDbPi1C76yPvPU-1deiQ0D6A+PHqFmdof4WOWIggYUXo6G+WCEXoy4YBfwPUNWU+XiwYoQ2gTwAAVo6PWHkD2KIpwC6EPo-NbsoP6PWOmgMMwH4PgRvmgHATaHVIgUQSPqECPOQOPM2EgDAHBsATnIVKgqmhhs2NAWiKpuNktmiGId+EBBIQtgZktitj4GiIaH4LKPdK5DuKEAASNnaC6KzGCP6FHE1K1tPM3HoUoN2CoIQRyl4m3FHF6GgZgRgNgbgUgPgYVm1nYKQaoT4FDjzkWCsHBopMuHBk1HnI9uYY4JEbwc2GCFrqEdhpjGpisGLC1hwVwSHIIDmBADwWYTepAWVv6L1poNCKIbIXvFIZsDIQEU5hUYwFUWINRvIa5gqEoVsEgKoZeBoZoFoS4jobkQYdnEYe4dPF1toKYSHGCBYYwdYUirYdnPYRgVgTga4HgS6MMe1qMV4emj4VwpoP4Q0SHEEWUfEeEYjJEc4LkXEWEdTnaBQEAA)

Comment: You need to fix the type of `TOPICS_TWO`: https://tsplay.dev/ND8D4N Previously, the type did not match the object.

Comment: @pink that is an answer

Answer (score 2):

The type of `TOPICS_TWO` shouldn't be a union. Since `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys` includes `TopicGroups`, you should exclude `TopicGroups` first. Then you can intersect the record with a new record of `TopicGroups`.

```
export const TOPICS_TWO: Record<
    Exclude<InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys, TopicGroups>,
    TopicConfiguration
> &
    Record<TopicGroups, TopicConfigurationGrouped> = {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#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-WIJn3w6EOoPi8gRjA1RXZ2hq8DayixA3o7COi2252e-2V3AiOu1XBPVOZ6H54uvuTHc7Q1mMNBDEQUE9KAfVhTgPXpRhA1pGAIMxJctG3XckXxUNMXIRsY1UOAVzLNxA0zJB3V-KBSGwotV0IwDNy-CEfyAuAJkTHZOHgNAAI3XoFRgqEM2-Qjs2AlxvVA8Cdig0TGDg2FEKDfcXTQjC4G9PNNBw8slMUs93QvXsB3I4dR3HJ9twmOBMC9acwLpHZX3g1TyLXKjfArTTmPPLtdOvW8nIfCBjJfMyLNUKyYJshdJnDckZj+B8WidF0rF4YsAkkEQVFzWEk2Vbt8NDQwdmykFQsYeEaLEfKLWAbsioggBxHBmFaXwKA6AsUE4WliX2AB+QNXggNs+BarRgA6oldh6vqBvdIb32mX56E-F18vAHYmHgISwBwMBOFyiFEpQZKoFSnbFIAKXsAANdsbHdEB1ooaLFrisq0BWyBGHW+qIEan0trSvaxAOo6Ts4c6rpuu6HsoFt4ASpKAh9FS4Cyqq7LgNqxqTElZFyTARzA9HRs6ia5DxgmkEmQG0GBlLtrB6MlNhAAeXxgHyKMTy0ZnODAPgo1UVHu3bGCYHdCZmYAel5-mWcltmOfQpjk1e2moHsUAwHdJGUYKqqGOptXQcU4SOlZ9nOY6M2ZcYAWhZF4AxaQCXpb5225YVznIph5i4dDNXvt+oSsKFg3VYR476ZNlnPa5zRzY5wW9eF0Xxal2Ore5y3M6t1R8BCiCgjgYAStDgAyMu45zzR7YL5j2xAFAwG9b068YaPq877nPdUewbEMQQ2B0KIAG024AXQdp2XYzrurfDcMpmrqXs-j+WLaV+bKVh50dHEIx7EDZBtigXxmdhGtkRdNFG9JZR0eW5Oap2UrH8q6reGKwOmvIGMMo6Eel8UKoikLfA4yh2ynCMGYSwehsj2HHoGZGHQ0yyCQsGA8EhQH7ExJA-Q0CLDWDuOjZc40cZQnQXJPi2McGHDwWcMwlwbjEKrqnJAgZ8DiEeGgXG3g-AfHaDnbYq1Pq8grP9HahsI7G0ZqbOezN4aHURpjEmOMnAzigMwZ2ah2y6IkZwUyktV7zxIQhPiREgKBlQbxWi-FiLtjUm4UxqkyH7BdEgquKClCUKvtQrqd9OD0IIUw24DhnFWy2uicBPjgFiBvrQiBUDziwPgeEjobCOFcI8DwuAzw3gCLSVoYRH11riPplIpRkc0odznmbRRR1i5Y38bIdRMBNHaNULo9s+jDHGOrm+Wp246LQCsemXwBELHQAcQ5SiG5fDhImOjRZsJAF7l8SAqJuCKixASEkFIaRMjwMQUyauqCYl1jidggJ7ZtlVD2akDIWQWHVwyQQLJng4B8OKNqTOxS1piPDpUjW4B3ThKGXYyxcBrHjPMQJaZJZcJLPRqs5CFysGbLobc3ZNQ6g2GOcgrQZzZLrMuRiiBWLqj7Meak1hjt3SZO4bwnw3zBG-NwCUgF9SAjAq1pTVhsLiKjNkDYwkkyoDwtLIqJFKygFovidck0CCPGnO8cS2J6KwG4MVWCul7CCAalGFqVlVs-miJgBUo638wUCqAv+VAkK2L2qQJxNw3ExkTIEuEtuu04Aj08VoaCsE6EmnZPYQpmhA0MjofqUU4pJTSm6LKcNcBI2STobqGNhp43aqruPaVjEt4xU-Kmiq2VcjIyJamzEw1NCvJYlIRg3YKAFopDFHefcB5DyiEfIkp9mZVsOMEFNElS1VT-icrQI8B0QJDREDk+Kq6VoklqxNbI51htpU7DhBqeR8mNcsgB07AmZrjcaVdSqJ2ZyXdZNNECT1GgTayDdLzdUcIFAqa07pfCdDtPu5FR72wZuFLGh9iqF0qrQcOm9uCgMGlPY+pNm76UEGiBaD9Kov0-sNT8hikwooLXgCXDcUB8YCDgNcdqmDR3dkvVC1VsrMHVukq+7CbSS5NpEjQu+vU1VotUQkzgNbsKuLkC6Hj-HRN5Sfp-CCzbC30CIwEUj8UpPv2fiVGgG5dgqAo2BN+ZbkbgrFdTYZJFMrsv+ea1671LNyaeoR3kSn0BOgk7IfTVV1MMGoFp3wKh3Mf0AhBWjkTNX0bWeq+V4DBNfFbQpxzJHnPWek4FnY397yaaYL58jlH-O0aMwJO1gERmvVM4VoCQnTWlKSyIr6DUwBCe9eJaDhwR7jzk+QSWkthyYGIyjNqjb2O733oYRwAJ2PkCWqGb+6VeOYMiyup9+Ht6+yGwfUwggADqOge0nzPrCGw1BhjMH8MzBj18rlRaHS6abUYH6qcKjJnYv84CVw6MfaAZ9rt1c4Fd+7HnHuMDS74cdyMUUYPO2SwJSSYFEIcOBnORKzuhnm3Q6HhC4HPJzlZZpFDZsES41FoJ5wQmY8zq8zhjLPnMoKVXSrALvT6ItXTapsj-Xxy5cBFRImWkaK0aZTpej6a9KrgMnO+XBV0eFTC2xYqJWIqrtj0mbmqy0Yg+czBrncFo5J2EtncAQsJPVxD0LiT8HJNh8+ue5P3k5Lye8Eoya6dWYZ+UwFIMo6s9qXU-2EdGmudae0-nXSelwCMXr0XXdxeQuhR6+xK5HJzIWdKgBSONkm8CRS+5Bynlw+VQjsLqK5sXa2VEHZlKHmHNJ1ba3lOvk0+rk7pn6tNagv5TLgSQqRWughVMxxyfJ2p9Jenm5pe7k4vqPDq9BfwfI+L5i0f2KqWV91y+rdbza-U4d7TizZqm88tby8m1xWY9H-FX32EB6B-hblXPmd57J9W0R9fovkP2w5tX8h-AO6jXhMb27gIVqbeoqBW7ExWjqVELqbqUuseQEXqEkPqfqtSAGs6HIyaAG962a56aBy66aeowGWaZ6T64SeaF+eGPsKso0kWLoIE6SoYggcUgY9a424YgY249BgIo0eOs+kOx4HQOgrwAAVh6O2PkCOFopwN6IPhqgJuGO2CXEdv4BIUAWgOwU6O1FwWngJrCN7OQDvN2EgDANRjQUUsnLjkwY2uhP6NiFBs0v5uptYXYQDg4X9gFl-HVmqNYeaP4MqJ9N+k2LCJQRdi6N6ELFCOGFXN1KtiNiPKEUoMOCoFISjsoOPFXIGPwUIRgCIWIUgBIYIHvAfLIT4b4HIrUpWBCNRopNuNRt1A4tzlCM4E4C4LEbIP6uGDUYrjjC6MrCxHAPoYYcnIIMWH5EJOZu-GYWxhYSwdYa5o4SlowM4eUclsVAseVEsXVO4b4J4bsEgD4feP4R0IEVEsEc0eEdXJEXkcNvYOtltjEaYXEeoYkbfpwCkdXGkYIcIaIW4OId6BcWtptjoIUSXMUXrpoGUase-JUS4e0XUXEY0U0XcS0V3G0bUQTl0eQEAA)

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are getting is because the type of `TOPICS` is not compatible with the union type you have defined as the return type of `getConfig`. The type `TOPICS` is a record with keys that belong to `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys` enum and its values can be either `TopicConfiguration` or `TopicConfigurationGrouped`. Therefore, when you try to access a value of `TOPICS` using an index of type `string` (returned by the configKey parameter of `getConfig`), TypeScript infers that the index is of type `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys`, which is not compatible with `string`. This is because TypeScript is not able to determine if the string is actually one of the enum values or not.

One way to fix this error is to change the return type of `getConfig` to be a union of `TopicConfiguration` and `TopicConfigurationGrouped` only, since `SecondaryTopicConfiguration` extends `TopicConfiguration`. This way, TypeScript will be able to infer the correct type of the value returned by `TOPICS` when accessed using an index of type `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys`. Here's an updated version of `getConfig`:

```
const getConfig = (
  configKey: InsuranceTopicKeys
): TopicConfiguration | TopicConfigurationGrouped | undefined => {
  const topicConfig = TOPICS[configKey];
  if (topicConfig) {
    return topicConfig;
  }
  return Object.values(TOPICS).find(
    (topicConfig) => topicConfig?.secondaryKey === configKey
  )?.secondaryTopic;
};
```

In this version, `configKey` is typed as `InsuranceTopicKeys`, which is the union of `InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys` and `InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys`. This ensures that the index used to access `TOPICS` is of the correct type.

Note that you don't need to define a separate type `TopicGroups` to represent the keys that belong to a `TopicConfigurationGrouped`. Instead, you can use the `Record` utility type to create a type that maps the keys of `TOPICS` to their respective value types, and then use a conditional type to filter out the keys that don't belong to a `TopicConfigurationGrouped`.
Here's an example:

```
type GroupedTopicKeys = {
  [K in keyof typeof TOPICS]: TOPICS[K] extends TopicConfigurationGrouped ? K : never;
}[keyof typeof TOPICS];

const groupedKeys: GroupedTopicKeys[] = ["CLAIMS"];

const groupedTopics: Record<GroupedTopicKeys, TopicConfigurationGrouped> = {
  [InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS]: {
    key: InsuranceTopicPrimaryKeys.CLAIMS,
    title: "Claims",
    component: TopicDrawerGroup,
    topicSelectorCreator: createMultiKeyedTopicSelector,
    sections: [
      SectionKeys.CLAIMANTS,
      SectionKeys.FULFILLED_CLAIMS,
      SectionKeys.UNFULFILLED_CLAIMS,
    ],
  },
};
```

In this example, the `GroupedTopicKeys` type is defined using a mapped type that filters out the keys of `TOPICS` that don't belong to a `TopicConfigurationGrouped`. The resulting type is a union of the remaining keys. The `groupedKeys` variable is then defined as an array of the keys that belong to a `TopicConfigurationGrouped`. Finally, a `groupedTopics` variable is defined as a record with keys of type `GroupedTopicKeys` and values of type `TopicConfigurationGrouped`.

Comment: Please use code formatting instead of bold formatting for identifiers

Comment: The issue isn't with the string input, in fact that's by design as elsewhere in the code I pass in strings that aren't `InsuranceTopicKeys`. The type narrowing should be provided by `isPrimaryTopic` should be sufficient. You're re-write of 'getConfig' just moves the type narrowing into that function, but wouldn't work as  `InsuranceTopicKeys` may be of `InsuranceTopicSecondaryKeys` type. **Also** as I stated elsewhere, I can't separate out `groupedTopics` from `TOPICS` as you have done so here, so that's also not helpful unfortunately.

Comment: Is this [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) generated?